# How can I add emphasis in an internal dialogue, given that I am already using italics for character thoughts?

Tags: dialogue

In a novel I am currently writing, characters frequently express thoughts. Following the advice I found [here](http://theeditorsblog.net/2012/02/28/inner-dialogue-writing-character-thoughts/), which states: "Never use quotation marks for thoughts, even if those thoughts are inner dialogue, a character talking to himself. Reserve quotation marks for speech that’s vocalized." It generally seems to be recommended to use italics when showing that a character is thinking instead of talking.

That's all fine, but now I am running into the problem that I also need to add emphasis sometimes. For example: "And what have *you* done all this time?" I usually also do this with italics, since boldface is too strong - It literally catches the attention too much.

But now my (probably stupid) problem: What do I do when a character is thinking something with emphasis?
Example: He thought *Yeah, YOU'RE one to talk*. Now, I could just use capital letters, as I did here for illustration purposes, but these look very unprofessional to me.

Does anyone have any advice on how to circumvent this problem?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*You could always* not italicize *parts that should stand out. The key point is to break up the flow of the text so that it is* visible *somehow.*

*Capitalization could be interpreted as an internal EMOTIONAL SHOUT more than a* sarcastic tone.

Comment: I feel like an idiot right now, for not having thought of that. Thank you very much!